# Magento 2 does not allow Special characters in First Name & Last name even though the Input Validation is None

Tags: magento2.4, customer-attribute, validation, special-character, customer-name

In my magento setup I am **not able to insert special characters for customer First name and Last name**.

The **Input Validation** for Customer Attribute First Name and Last Name **is NONE**.
But still Magento 2 not allowing me to insert special characters for customer First name and Last name.

I also checked in a fresh magento 2 installation setup and there I am able to insert special characters.

Please help. I am using Magento 2.4.2

**Customer Attribute configurations:**

[image]

**Frontend - Create Account:**

[image]

Comment: Hi Kaushik did you find the solution ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `\Magento\Customer\Model\Validator\Name::isValidName`

Magento matches the first name of the customer with the regex pattern

`private const PATTERN_NAME = '/(?:[\p{L}\p{M}\,\-\_\.\'\s\d]){1,255}+/u';`

```
 /**
 * Check if name field is valid.
 *
 * @param string|null $nameValue
 * @return bool
 */
private function isValidName($nameValue)
{
    if ($nameValue != null) {
        if (preg_match(self::PATTERN_NAME, $nameValue, $matches)) {
            return $matches[0] == $nameValue;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vyacheslav,

Answer (score -1):

where can I find \Magento\Customer\Model\Validator\Name::isValidName to edit the private const PATTERN_NAME?

Regards